# Can't update map column of DynamoDB table

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently developing a skill for Amazon's echo dot which requires the use of persistent data. I ran into an issue when developing a web interface for my skill where I was not able to easily update the `mapAttr` column of the DynamoDB table used by the skill.

I've been trying to work this out for the last 2 days, I've looked everywhere including the documentation but can't seem to find anything that'll help me.

This is the code I am using:

```
        $result = $client->updateItem([
            'TableName' => 'rememberThisDBNemo',
            'Key' => [
                'userId' => [ 'S' => $_SESSION['userDataAsk'] ]
            ],
            'ExpressionAttributeNames' => [
                '#attr' => 'mapAttr.ReminderJSON'
            ],
            'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
                ':val1' => json_encode($value)
            ],
            'UpdateExpression' => 'SET #attr = :val1'
        ]);
```

I have tried many different things so this might be just absolutely wrong, but nothing that I have found has worked.

The table has *2 columns*, **userId** and **mapAttr**, userId is a string and mapAttr is a map. Originally I thought it was simply a JSON string but it was not like that as when I tried to update it with a JSON string directly it would stop working when read by Alexa.

I am only trying to update 1 out of the 2 attributes of mapAttr. That is ReminderJSON which is a string.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling updateItem like this

```
    $result = $client->updateItem([
        'TableName' => 'rememberThisDBNemo',
        'Key' => [
            'userId' => [ 'S' => $_SESSION['userDataAsk'] ]
        ],
        'ExpressionAttributeNames' => [
            '#mapAttr' => 'mapAttr',
            '#attr' => 'ReminderJSON'
        ],
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
            ':val1' => ['S' => json_encode($value)]
        ],
        'UpdateExpression' => 'SET #mapAttr.#attr = :val1'
    ]);
```

However, please be aware that in order for this to work, **attribute mapAttr must already exist**. If it doesn't, you'll get ValidationException saying `The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update...`

As a workaround, you may want to add a `ConditionExpression => 'attribute_exists(mapAttr)'` to your params, catch possible exception, and then perform another update adding a new attribute mapAttr:

```
  try {
    $result = $client->updateItem([
        'TableName' => 'rememberThisDBNemo',
        'Key' => [
            'userId' => [ 'S' => $_SESSION['userDataAsk'] ]
        ],
        'ExpressionAttributeNames' => [
            '#mapAttr' => 'mapAttr'
            '#attr' => 'ReminderJSON'
        ],
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
            ':val1' => ['S' => json_encode($value)]
        ],
        'UpdateExpression' => 'SET #mapAttr.#attr = :val1'
        'ConditionExpression' => 'attribute_exists(#mapAttr)'
    ]);

  } catch (\Aws\Exception\AwsException $e) {
    if ($e->getAwsErrorCode() == "ConditionalCheckFailedException") {
      $result = $client->updateItem([
          'TableName' => 'rememberThisDBNemo',
          'Key' => [
              'userId' => [ 'S' => $_SESSION['userDataAsk'] ]
          ],
          'ExpressionAttributeNames' => [
              '#mapAttr' => 'mapAttr'
          ],
          'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
              ':mapValue' => ['M' => ['ReminderJSON' => ['S' => json_encode($value)]]]
          ],
          'UpdateExpression' => 'SET #mapAttr = :mapValue'
          'ConditionExpression' => 'attribute_not_exists(#mapAttr)'
      ]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried both approaches but neither of them seem to have worked. There has been one common strange thing with many of my attempts though: *a lot of responses are usually blank, but return a standard 200 HTTP response code*, I have tried catching exceptions with both `AwsException` and `DynamoDbException` but I cannot catch anything.

Comment: Could it be that you just didn't notice that instead of updating the ReminderJSON item inside of mapAttr map, you were creating a new top level attribute `mapAttr.ReminderJSON` (yes, with a dot in its name). Because it's exactly what you get if you specify `'#attr' => 'mapAttr.ReminderJSON'` like shown in your code snippet. Notice that the map and attribute names are specified differently in my example.